# How to choose a random Value from Assoc array then display the key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Hello I am trying to display a random value key pair separately in a string. I want the value and key to remain together.

```
charAT = {
         'Flamethrower' : Math.floor(Math.random()*(15-5+1)+5),
         'Headbut' : Math.floor(Math.random()*(5-3+1)+3),
         'Fireblast' : Math.floor(Math.random()*(25-10+1)+10),
         'Tailwhip': 0
     };
```

Want this but for assoc array

```
rand = charAT[Math.floor(Math.random() * charAT.length)];
```

Example Code Wanted

```
alert('charizard used '+ rand:key + 'and did ' + rand:value + ' damage!')
```

Wanted Output

charizard used flamethrower and did 12 damage!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: `Object.keys()`

Comment: @zerkms With using Object.keys() can you keep the value and pair together?

Comment: No, but you don't need to. Pick random key, then get the value using it.

Comment: @zerkms In this scenario how would that look? I need the number to match if I use Object.keys() how can I tell it to match specifically to the randomly chosen key?

Comment: What does `Object.keys()` return?

Comment: @zerkms Every key, Sorry I am JS illiterate so I may be doing this wrong. Object.key(charAT) displays all of them how do I narrow it to one.

Comment: "how do I narrow it to one" --- you **ALREADY** have that code in your question.

Comment: Sorry -.- I herped before I derped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a array filled with the object property names. 
So, applying a random index on that array, you can get a random property name, then you can use it to get the random property value desired.

```js
 var charAT = {
     'Flamethrower' : Math.floor(Math.random()*(15-5+1)+5),
     'Headbut' : Math.floor(Math.random()*(5-3+1)+3),
     'Fireblast' : Math.floor(Math.random()*(25-10+1)+10),
     'Tailwhip': 0
 };

 var ix = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(charAT).length);
 var rand = Object.keys(charAT)[ix];
 alert(rand + ":" + charAT[rand]);
```